# Using a "slide" effect to show/hide an <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Consider the following JSFiddle, which uses jQuery's `slideToggle` (i.e. `slideUp` or `slideDown`) to reveal/hide an input element:

http://jsfiddle.net/sfN9C/

The top input looks wonky while sliding up and down, because I am sliding the element directly.

The second input looks much nicer.

Can I get the second effect, but without the extra div?

jQuery allowed. Dynamically inserting extra divs via JavaScript not preferred; hoping there's something nicer I can do.

Comment: You'll need to wrap it inside a parent element (div or similar) if it is not already. Otherwise you can do sth this: `$('input').parent().slideToggle();`

If the input element comes along with some other elements inside its parent they'll of course collapse, too. Suggestion: `$('input').wrap('<div />').parent().slideToggle();`

Comment: @kernel that breaks any css that targets the input with sibling or child combinators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the input display as block helps and seems to work in IE7. Leave it to you to decide if acceptable UI or not

http://jsfiddle.net/sfN9C/1/

Comment: Nice! Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: It's still a little jumping in Chrome 17.

Comment: @kernel in my Chrome 17 it's not "jumpy" in the same way as the original, but it does animate away the margins as well, so the input moves upwards (but smoothly). Which is actually desired, since it needs to leave behind no trace of itself when it's all done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, as `slideToggle` actually animates the height of the element. In your second example (with the wrapper div), it's the div that's animated and the input stays the same height, just appears or reappears as though a curtain is drawn up in front of it.

Comment: Yes, I realize that's what's happening; that's the entire point of me asking the question.